# Alert after $.post shows different data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Look this code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="finalvalue" value="2" />

<script>
    $.post("/increment_in_one", { param: 2 }, function (data) {
        alert( data ); // this shows: 3
        $("#finalvalue").val( data );
        alert( $("#finalvalue").val() ); // this shows 3
    });

    alert( $("#finalvalue").val() );   // this shows 2
</script>
```

Why does the last alert show 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the code doesn't run in sync as you'd expect from the coding. The `$.post` call executes asynchronously "in the background". As soon as you call `$.post`, the webbrowser will spawn a new thread which does all the task and the current thread just immediately continues with the remnant of the function, which is the `alert()` which displays `2`. The new background thread in turn connects the webserver, fires a HTTP POST and then finally invokes the callback function. It takes more time than the initial thread needs to call the `alert()`. That's why you see the difference.

In this particular code example, you should have noticed that by seeing `2` being alerted *before* `3`. Try adding more sensible information to the alert, e.g.

```
alert('Inside $.post callback: ' + $("#finalvalue").val());
```

and

```
alert('At end of function: ' + $("#finalvalue").val());
```

All with all, if you want to do some stuff based on the new data, the code should then go inside the callback function.